# Why can't I read signs that are placed higher or lower than eye-level?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I try to read a sign on Minecraft PE I cant see it unless it's 2 blocks high. I can't read high or low signs for some reason.

I've tried:

- Breaking and putting the sign back,
- Turning Graphics off
- Restarting the app
- Loading a new world

It's really frustrating, I can't read my signs unless I am close to the sign!

Comment: Hi Shawn, welcome to Arqade :). I've taken the liberty of fixing up the wording & grammar of your post, you'll find you get a nicer response & more upvotes if people can interpret what you're trying to say. :) Also: when you say 'Turning Graphics off' - do you mean 'Fancy Graphics'?

Comment: Also, could you add what platform (Android, iOS, Win10) and what version of the game you are refering) I have played many version and haven't really noticed this issue, but perhaps if I knew more I could figure it out for you and anybody who might find this later on.